# Meaning of "things are swept under the rug"

Tags: meaning

I was wondering what it means as analogy that

> quite a few things are swept under the rug.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[Swept under the rug](http://www.wordnik.com/words/sweep%20under%20the%20rug)* (or carpet) is an idiom meaning to conceal something that is embarrassing that you don't want other people to know about.

Think about cleaning the floor. You have all the dirt, and are too lazy or out of time to find something to pick it up, so you lift the corner of the rug and sweep it there.

Comment: The idiom carries this meaning of concealing or disposing of something *instead of dealing with it correctly*.

Answer (score -1):

A sudden announcement of visitors leaves the surprised host with a quick cleaning up of the room, by brushing lots of muck under the carpet and make it look quite spruced up for the occasion.

Comment: The example I have given is from what a close  relative of mine literally did when some guests were announced, without prior notice.   She quickly swept the muck and hid it under the carpet, to make the place look clean, presentable.  Ironically, the visitor, of a critical demeanor, praised the well kept place, and then, praising the carpet, its design, slyly lifted it up from one corner, as though, examining its texture, and to her delight, discovered the 'shortcut' to this tidiness.